# Close the div by clicking the button inside the div

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to close the ng-repeat div on click the button

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="indexVal in vm.flowObject track by $index">
    <div ng-show="listItems.title=='Menu'" class="Margin_Set" id="div2" scroll>
        <button>
            Close div
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
 $scope.listItems = [{
      name: "some name",
      title: "Menu"
  }];
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uey4xr5L/

Comment: close in the sense you mean hide it ??

Answer (score 0):

You can add a property *hidden* and set it to *true* on click:

```html
<div ng-repeat="indexVal in vm.flowObject track by $index">
    <div ng-hide="indexVal.hidden == true" class="Margin_Set" id="div2" scroll>
        <button ng-click="indexVal.hidden = true"> Close div </button>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: what is your method? please recheck your answer its not working

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
 $scope.listItems = [{
      name: "some name",
      title: "Menu"
    }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myCtrl"> <!-- ng-repeat="indexVal in vm.flowObject track by $index" -->
       <p> {{listItems[0]}} </p>
       <button ng-show="listItems[0].close=='true'" ng-click="listItems[0].close = 'false'">Open div</button>
        <div ng-show="(listItems[0].title=='Menu' && listItems[0].close!='true')" class="Margin_Set" id="div2" scroll>
 <!-- as per your scenario change the condition.. -->
<p>{{listItems[0].name}}</p>
              <button ng-click="listItems[0].close = 'true'">
              Close div
              </button>

              </div>
              </div>
              </body>
```